# VSTS Workflow for Microservices / Share Service Endpoints

Tags: azure-devops, microservices, sharing, endpoint, projects

We're using VSTS to deploy to an Azure Container Service (AKS) which is running Kubernetes.  We are building out a collection of microservices to share between several applications and, for the time being, this Kubernetes instance will manage most or all of our service orchestration.

My confusion is with VSTS and the fact that - as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/service-endpoints):

> Service endpoints are created at project scope. An endpoint created in one project is not visible in another team project.

Right now each microservice is its own project in VSTS.  We have another project for changes/updates to the Kubernetes Ingress (NGINX) services.  Each of these projects feels well-defined in terms of no overlap, different CI/CD tasks, etc.

But, this means that for every single project, we have to set up duplicate Service Endpoints for Kubernetes (not to mention our private GitHub repos).  Apparently that is the intent of VSTS, but is there some other feature / workflow I'm missing that avoids all this redundancy?

I've looked into Deployment Pools / Groups but that's a different use case.  I've also tried creating Teams, sharing across projects, etc. but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely right. At this moment, there is nothing which allows you to share service endpoints between projects. And I strongly feel that this needs to be addressed.

The only workaround that I see for you is to write a small tool which will provision/update your endpoints across all the projects using [VSTS Rest Apis.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/endpoints/endpoints)

There is already a [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11701410-vsts-add-services-on-project-collection-level) request for this.

Comment: thank you for the answer and the link!  Not what I was hoping to hear but at least I know now!